# Magento 1 Variable to check if customer is subscribed to newletter

Tags: magento-1.7, variables

Is there a variable I can include in the transactional emails to show whether the customer has subscribed to the Newsletter or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php there is a function **sendNewOrderEmail()**  you can see this code:

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'        => $this,
                'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
            )
        );
```

in same function you can check if customer is subscribed to newsletter or not like using this code:

```
$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($this->getCustomerEmail());
if ($subscriber->getId()) {
     $is_subscribed=true;
}
else{
$is_subscribed=false;
}
```

then you can pass this variable in in setTemplateParams like:

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'        => $this,
                'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
                'is_subscribed' = > $is_subscribed
            ));
```

then in email template you can check like this

```
{{if is_subscribed}}
```

Note: override this function instead of making changes in core code

Answer (score 0):

You can check customer by email if the email is already in subscribe list

$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
if ($subscriber->getId()) {
     // put your logic here...
}

Or if you have customer ID then you can directly check in newsletter_subscriber table to check if customer ID exists or not.

Comment: But I can't do this within a transactional email template I guess